# detect scrolll on web browser control compact framework

Tags: winforms, compact-framework, webbrowser-control

In Windows Forms, with the WebBrowser control there is a way to detect scroll and on that scroll fire off an event. Can this be done in the compact framework 3.5?

I am building a form that has a WebBrowser control on it, and when the user scrolls to the end of the document, then I need to show a button to move to next form.

Can this be done?

Comment: is there a way to do this with some com stuff or something? i know that the full dot net framework for the web browser control has the Document property but not in compact framework edition.

Comment: I need to know the same thing did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @Pomster See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343452/detect-scroll-on-a-webbrowser-control and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115043/create-event-handler-for-onscroll-for-web-browser-control as well as http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/ab170146-a5b9-4d2d-bbca-dc98cb164311