# I would like to create an event handler

Tags: c#, event-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create event handler for OnScroll for web browser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115043/create-event-handler-for-onscroll-for-web-browser-control)

I would like to create an event handler for a web browser control **scrolling**.

```
webCompareSQL.Document.Window.Scroll
```

Can some one show me how to create an event handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the class you add a delegate and an event, and usually a simple internal method that checks for null and calls the event:

```
public delegate void ScrollHandler();
public event ScrollHandler Scrolled;
internal void OnScrolled()
{
    if (this.Scrolled != null)
        this.Scrolled();
}
```

Then in the actual code you would register a method for the event using:

```
MyClass.Scrolled += new ScrollHandler(MyMethod);

void MyMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("It was scrolled.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks i'm still figuring out how it works :)

Comment: Thanks this looks good for creating an event handler. This webCompareSQL.Document.Window.Scroll this code is and even or i think it is because when i typed it in there was lightning next to the scroll, is there any way i can write an even handler for this?